# Hide parent component in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In react router is there a way to have child routes but not display the parent component? I'm trying to display breadcrumbs in my application so I switched to having child routes but I don't want to display the parent component in the way of a 'master/detail' type layout. I just want the child component displayed as if it were navigated to by itself but it seems if you don't include `{this.props.children}` somewhere in the parent component then then child component never gets rendered.

One hack I've tried is seeing if `this.props.children` is populated and not displaying the rest of the page in render like

```
if(this.props.children) {
   return (this.props.children) 
} else { 
  return /**rest of render method**/
}
```

but this feels like a bad solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you're trying to do, but it seems `<IndexRoute>` could help you, since that lets you distinguish what you do at `/portal` vs. `/portal/feature`

```
<Route path="/portal" component={ComponentContainingBreadcrumbs}>
  <IndexRoute component={ComponentWithRestofRenderMethodFromYourExample} />
  <Route path="child1" component={Child1} />
  <Route path="child2" component={Child2} />
</Route>
```